# PIVOT change all NULL to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, pivot

I have the out of the PIVOT for below with some NULL values. I had to paste into excel and change all nulls to 0 which is very time consuming.
How do I change all NULL to 0 for the output of the pivot:

```
select * from 
(
     SELECT
         Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO,
         isnull(sum([Period DATA     6b].LI_QTY+[Period DATA 6b].RG_QTY*1.0),0) as "TotalUnits"
     FROM Calender INNER JOIN
         [Period DATA 6b] ON Calender.[Starting Period] = [Period DATA     6b].STARTING_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
         Allproducts ON [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO = Allproducts.PRODUCT_NO
     where Calender.YrPer >= '2012P05'
     group by Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO

     UNION

     SELECT
         'TotalPerProduct' YrPer, 
         [Period DATA 6b].
         PRODUCT_NO, 
         isnull(sum([Period     DATA 6b].LI_QTY+[Period DATA 6b].RG_QTY*1.0),0) as "TotalUnits"
     FROM
          Calender INNER JOIN
          [Period DATA 6b] ON Calender.[Starting Period] = [Period DATA     6b].STARTING_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Allproducts ON [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO = Allproducts.PRODUCT_NO
      where Calender.YrPer >= '2012P05'
      group by [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO

)
as test1
pivot
(
    sum(TotalUnits)
    for YrPer
    in ([2012P05],[2012P06],[2012P07],[2012P08],[2012P09],[2012P10],[2012P11],[2012P12],    [2012P13],[2013P01],[2013P02],[2013P03],[2013P04],[2013P05],[2013P06],[2013P07],[2013P08],    [2013P09],[2013P10],[2013P11],[2013P12],[2013P13],[2014P01],[2014P02],[2014P03],[2014P04],     [TotalPerProduct])
)
PivotTable
order by PRODUCT_NO
```

Comment: Can you not do a FIND/REPLACE in Excel (CTRL-H) and replace all NULL with 0?  If not, then you'd need to select your pivoted data into a temp table, and update every column in the temp table with 0, then copy that into Excel.

Comment: Hi JiggsJedi, I already use this method but when I am working with 500K rows and 10+ columns, Excel takes time. I thought if I can do this in sql it will save some time.

Comment: Then you'll need to pull the resultset into a temp table, and do updates on every column, then select from the temp table.  Only some of the aggregate functions eliminate NULLS in a PIVOT, and SUM() isn't one of them.

Comment: Sorry, you are suggesting to create a temp table in SQL server. I see. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if your pivoted columns are going to keep expanding, you might want to look at a dynamic pivot that automatically adds new columns for you as the months roll on.

Comment: Interesting point. I will research in to Dynamic Pivot. If I need, I will create a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "select * from ...." to "Select isnull(column1,0) as column1......
Not sure this what you want?

Comment: This wouldn't apply to the PIVOT's aggregate function.

Comment: Insert the resultset into a temp table (# table) and select isnull(column1,0) as column1, ... from #Temp table. Use select * into #Temp table

Comment: Thank you Henry and JiggsJedi

Comment: Actually Henry, your suggestion works: isnull(column1,0) as column1 for each column on the main select